# OpenGL ES 2.0 Android - Triangle color definition

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, rgb

I'm doing a tutorial on OpenGL ES for Android located [here](http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-one-getting-started/)

My question is about the colors of the triangles. Take this triangle for example:

```
// This triangle is red, green, and blue.
final float[] triangle1VerticesData = {
    // X, Y, Z, 
    // R, G, B, A
    -0.5f, -0.25f, 0.0f, 
    *1.0f,* 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,

    0.5f, -0.25f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,

    0.0f, 0.559016994f, 0.0f, 
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
```

at the first vertex why is red defined as 1.0f ? I was thinking it would be 255. Why is the total 1.0f ?
if i go to a site like this http://html-color-codes.info/ to get the color i want its showing in 255 toal not 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colors in OpenGL are scaled in the range 0 to 1 (floating point). To convert 8bit color values (0 -255 integer) just divide the value by 255 and you will get the desired color.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way colors are defined in OpenGL when specifying them with float values. The range of each component is 0.0 to 1.0.

Using a range of 0 to 255 makes sense when using byte values, because that's the range available in an unsigned 8-bit number.

Since floats don't cover a fixed range (*), the range used to define colors is somewhat arbitrary. Using 0.0 to 1.0 makes about as much sense as anything. You can look at the component values as fractions. For example, 0.0 for red means "no red", and 1.0 means "all available red". Using fractions to express values that go from "none" to "all" is very common, and values from 0.0 to 1.0 are the floating point representation of those fractions.

(*) There obviously is a range of values that can be represented by floats, but using the full range would not make sense in this context.